# Changing default runtime serverless v1.0

Tags: python, lambda, serverless-framework

Trying to use serverless v1.0 alpha, but cannot set the runtime variable. I tried setting it in serverless.yaml as:

```
service: want_python
provider: aws
functions:
    hello:
        runtime: python
        handler: handler.hello
```

But it always shows a runtime of nodejs. I also tried python2.7 and that did not work as well. I can get it to work no problem in v0.5 by changing runtime in s-function.json, I figured it would be the same...Folder with the files is as such:

```
$ ls -lha
handler.py
serverless.env.yaml
serverless.yaml
```

handler.py and serverless.env.yaml are boilerplate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [Serverless v1.0-Beta.1](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-v1-0-beta-release-1/) you're already able to use python.

You can create a python service this way:

```
sls create -t aws-python
```

Then you'll get a `serverless.yml` that will have the provider and runtime configured like this:

```
provider: 
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's changed very recently, only Node.js is supported in the alpha.

> At the moment we only support Node.js in this alpha, but other
>   languages will follow.

http://blog.serverless.com/serverless-v1-0-alpha1-announcement/

EDIT:

v1.0 went beta August 3rd, so you should be good to go now.